# Drawing a simple library dependency scheme

Tags: java, c++, c, uml, visio

I am looking for a tool and a guide/example to show how you can write a simple picture that explains the relationship between the following components:

- A java applet
- A c++ library
- A java wrapper for the C++ library (using JNI)
- A c library

The applet is using the java wrapper methods. 
The java wrapper is a wrapper for the c++ library. It is possible to invoke methods both ways (C++ --> java, java --> c++)
The c++ library is basically an interface for the c library.

I got argoUML and Microsoft Visio; anything works, just some simple picture displaying this, it dosn't have to be too specific or pretty (just not paint-level).

Can someone point me to resources explaining how to picture program relationships like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UML tutorial of Enterprise Architect [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/) may give you some idea about the several UML diagrams that are of use to your needs.
In general dependencies are shown in class diagrams (between several classes), package diagrams (between namespaces/libraries) and component diagrams.

If you ask more specifically about UML representation of something in your mind I will be of help.

Comment: Where do you put method declarations in a component diagram? For example my c++ library exposes several methods used by the java wrapper.

Comment: Methods appear in class and sequence diagrams. In your case you have dependency between the two packages (C++ and Java) and a relation between the Java and C++ classes. If you want to draw the details of the dependencies to the method level I think UML is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a UML [Component Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [jGraph](http://jgraph.com/) will be helpful for you?
Cheers